# Always keep on keyboard in android on focus to next Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having 20 entries and these are created dynamically through loop. and on textchanges i have set focus to the next entry ,having focus to next entry keyboard hides and than show again and it happen on every text change.I want that keyboard should not hide every time after textchange it show always show till the last 20th entry..

----My Custom Entry

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsFocusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(MyEntry), false, propertyChanged: OnChanged);

    static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var entry = bindable as MyEntry;

        var focus = (bool)newValue;

        if (focus)
        {
            entry.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            entry.Unfocus();
        }

    }

    public bool IsFocus
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFocusProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsFocusProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MyEntry()
    {
        this.Focused += MyEntry_Focused;
        this.Unfocused += MyEntry_Unfocused;
    }

    private void MyEntry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsFocus = false;
    }

    private void MyEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsFocus = true;
    }
   }
```

--My model

```
public  class CrossingUIModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string fieldValue;
    public string FieldValue
    {
        get { return fieldValue; }
        set
        {
            if (fieldValue != value)
            {
                fieldValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FieldValue));
            }
               
        }
    }


    private bool isFocus = false;
    public bool IsFocus
    {
        get { return isFocus; }
        set
        {
            if (isFocus != value)
            {
                isFocus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsFocus));
            }
                                  
        }
    }




}
```

--my View Model

```
    public void CreateUI()
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();

        BindCrossingUIModel = new ObservableCollection<CrossingUIModel>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
        {
            CrossingUIModel model = new CrossingUIModel();
            model.Id = i;
            BindCrossingUIModel.Add(model);
        }

        foreach (CrossingUIModel model in BindCrossingUIModel)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }

        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();

    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "FieldValue")
        {
            var model = sender as CrossingUIModel;

            if (model.FieldValue.Length == 1)
            {
                model.FieldValue = model.FieldValue.Substring(0, 1);
                model.IsFocus = false;
                int id = model.Id;
               
                if (id == 20)
                {
                    var FocusControl = _page.FindByName<Entry>("Amt");

                    if (FocusControl != null)
                    {
                        FocusControl.Focus();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    BindCrossingUIModel[id].IsFocus = true;

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

--xaml file

```
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Entry x:Name="Fields" Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       ReturnType="Next" MaxLength="1" Keyboard="Numeric" 
                                       TextChanged="Fields_TextChanged" ></Entry>
                            </StackLayout>-->

                            <StackLayout WidthRequest="100"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                <local:MyEntry WidthRequest="80" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="50" 
                                               x:Name="Fields" Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                               IsFocus="{Binding IsFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                               ReturnType="Next"  Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1"
                                    ></local:MyEntry>
                            </StackLayout>



                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have shared code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the code by removing the line `model.IsFocus = false;`

```
private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "FieldValue")
        {
            var model = sender as CrossingUIModel;

            if (model.FieldValue.Length == 1)
            {
                model.FieldValue = model.FieldValue.Substring(0, 1);
                
                int id = model.Id;
                
                if (id == 20)
                {
                    var FocusControl = _page.FindByName<Entry>("Amt");

                    if (FocusControl != null)
                    {
                        FocusControl.Focus();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    BindCrossingUIModel[id].IsFocus = true;

                }
            }

        }
```